# Connection refused: Identifier rejected when try to connect with MQTT broker

Tags: angular, websocket, mqtt, iot, identifier

I am trying to connect my MQTT broker from angular using `MQTTJS`. I want to show notification in my website at least once when any message send from anyone on particular topic. but My MQTT connection throw error like : `Connection refused: Identifier rejected`

For Connection, I used this configuration  :

```
var config = {
      host: <broker url>,
      protocol: 'mqtts',
      username: <username>,
      password: <password>,
      clientId: <client_ID>      
      keepalive: <keeplive time>,
      reconnectPeriod: 10,
      port: 61619,
      clean: false,
      queueQoSZero: false,
}
```

I can't understand why MQTT throw this error. where am I doing wrong? 
any little-bit help would be helpful for me. please help me.

I tried clean: true in configuration that will create new session every time when connect. But due to that, I can't receive my QOS : 1's message after connection.

Answer (score 1):

If this is running in the browser, you can't use `mqtts` as the protocol you must use `ws` or `wss` and the broker must be configured to support MQTT over WebSockets.

Also just to be clear, the `host` field really should be just a hostname, not a URL